# can not tweet through python using twitterapi

Tags: python, twitter

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api()
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='bkvRjwyoMnBo1EWw',consumer_secret='9Cg4oXgk0eIphAnewppB0sXlHQ1cBhkk',access_token_key='27436-GlzGFHPgbgGQV5RRc8oSiqeY4XsDZ',access_token_secret='fwekIDmxTPy3ZDdoVh5EVcQOxzg')
>>> status = api.PostUpdate('I love python-twitter!')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    status = api.PostUpdate('I love python-twitter!')
  File "c:\python27\python-twitter-0.8.2\twitter.py", line 2766, in PostUpdate
    data = self._ParseAndCheckTwitter(json)
  File "c:\python27\python-twitter-0.8.2\twitter.py", line 3668, in _ParseAndCheckTwitter
    self._CheckForTwitterError(data)
  File "c:\python27\python-twitter-0.8.2\twitter.py", line 3691, in _CheckForTwitterError
    raise TwitterError(data['error'])
TwitterError: Read-only application cannot POST
>>> dir(twitter)
['ACCESS_TOKEN_URL', 'AUTHORIZATION_URL', 'Api', 'CHARACTER_LIMIT', 'DEFAULT_CACHE', 'DirectMessage', 'Hashtag', 'List', 'REQUEST_TOKEN_URL', 'SIGNIN_URL', 'Status', 'StringIO', 'Trend', 'TwitterError', 'Url', 'User', '_FileCache', '_FileCacheError', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', '__warningregistry__', 'base64', 'calendar', 'datetime', 'gzip', 'httplib', 'md5', 'oauth', 'os', 'parse_qs', 'parse_qsl', 'rfc822', 'simplejson', 'sys', 'tempfile', 'textwrap', 'time', 'urllib', 'urllib2', 'urlparse']
```

How to recover this TwitterError?

Comment: Did you read the error message? "Read-only application cannot POST" - which implies that your access credentials are read-only.

Comment: @Amber yes I read it but I want to know how to change it . If i want to POST what should I do ?

Comment: In your app's settings (at https://dev.twitter.com/apps) you need to set it to be a read and write app.

Comment: @Amber thanks it's work . I change it to read, write and access direct message.

Comment: Great. Posted the same an answer so you can mark it as solving your problem.

Comment: have you people paid for correct answers and reputation ? I ma fairly new to this website . Don't know why every one ask me this

Comment: Nope! Everyone who answers questions here does so entirely voluntarily on their own time. :) Reputation is just a number, once you get past a certain point it doesn't mean anything (http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#reputation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install python_twitter because the commands you use belongs from Python_twitter and I think you follow the documentation of twitter. You need to check this . All your questions have same problems. Kindly check it.You need to change your application to read/write.

Answer (score 2):

In your app's settings (at dev.twitter.com/apps) you need to set it to be a read and write app.